# Scanf skipped in loop (Hangman)

Tags: c, loops, scanf

This program essentially asks for a secret string, then asks a user to repeatedly guess single chars of that string until he guesses it all. It works however every second time the while loop is run it skips user input for the guessed char. How do I fix this?

```
int main(){
  char guess;
  char test2 [50];
  char * s = test2;

  char output [50];
  char * t = output;


  printf("Enter the secret string:\n");
  fgets(test2, 50, stdin);
  for (int i=0;i<49;i++){    //fills ouput with _ spaces
    *(output +i)='_';

  while(strcmp(s,t) != 0){
    printf("Enter a guess:");
    scanf("%c",&guess);
    printf("You entered: %c\n", guess);
    showGuess(guess,s, t );           // makes a string "output" with guesses in it
    printf("%s\n",t);
  }
  printf("Well Done!");
}
```

Comment: You are also comparing stuff with the `'\n'` the user entered.

Comment: and need output null-terminate.

Comment: After each letter input, you probably want to change the contents of `output`. Otherwise you will be comparing the same things over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick and dirty solution try

```
// the space in the format string consumes optional spaces, tabs, enters
if (scanf(" %c", &guess) != 1) /* error */;
```

For a better solution redo your code to use `fgets()` and then parse the input.

Comment: Neither of those work. The guessed string never matches the input string. :(

Comment: Exactly like the solution of @User231454, this is going to ignore the spaces. So if the input string has spaces, it will not be possible to complete the game. Otherwise, the logic is better than the one in my (current) solution: it can actually warn the player that the input is not valid rather than ignoring the invalid part of the input.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in some other answers and comments, you need to "consume" the "newline character" in the input.

The reason for that is that the input from your keyboard to the program is buffered by your shell, and so, the program won't see anything until you actually tell your shell to "pass the content of its buffer to the program". At this point, the program will be able to read the data contained in the previous buffer, e.g. your input, followed by one the character(s) used to validate your input in the shell: the newline. If you don't "consume" the newline before you do another `scanf`, that second `scanf` will read the newline character, resulting in the "skipped `scanf`" you've witnessed. To consume the extra character(s) from the input, the best way is to read them and discard what you read (what the code below does, notice the

```
while(getc(stdin) != '\n');
```

line after your `scanf`. What this line does is: "while the character read from `stdin` is not `'\n'`, do nothing and loop.").

As an alternative, you could tell your shell to not buffer the input, via the [`termios(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios) functions, or you could use either of the [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29)/[ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) libraries for the I/O.

So here is what you want:

```
int main(){
  char guess;
  char test2 [50];
  char * s = test2; // 3. Useless

  char output [50];
  char * t = output; // 3. Useless

  int i;  // 8. i shall be declared here.

  printf("Enter the secret string:\n");
  fgets(test2, 50, stdin);
  for (i=0;i<50;i++) if (test2[i] == '\n') test2[i] = '\0'; // 4. Remove the newline char and terminate the string where the newline char is.
  for (int i=0;i<49;i++){ // 5. You should use memset here; 8. You should not declare 'i' here.
    *(output +i)='_';
  } // 1. Either you close the block here, or you don't open one for just one line.
  output[49] = '\0'; // 6. You need to terminate your output string.

  while(strcmp(s,t) != 0){ // 7. That will never work in the current state.
    printf("Enter a guess:");
    scanf("%c",&guess);
    while(getc(stdin) != '\n');
    printf("You entered: %c\n", guess);
    showGuess(guess,s, t );
    printf("%s\n",t);
  }
  printf("Well Done!");
  return 0; // 2. int main requires that.
}
```

Other comments on your code:

1. You opened a block after your `for` loop and never closed it. That might be causing problems.
2. You declared your `main` as a function returning an integer... So you should at least `return 0;` at the end.
3. You seem to have understood that `char * t = output;` copies `output`'s value and uses `t` as a name for the new copy. This is wrong. You are indeed copying something, but you only copy the address (a.k.a reference) of `output` in `t`. As a result, `output` and `t` refer to the same data, and if you modify `output`, `t` will get modified; and *vice versa*. Otherwise said, those `t` and `s` variables are useless in the current state.
4. You also need to remove the newline character from your input in the test2 buffer. I have added a line after the `fgets` for that.
5. Instead of setting all the bytes of an array "by hand", please consider using the `memset` function instead.
6. You need to actually *terminate* the output string after you "fill" it, so you should allocate a `'\0'` in last position.
7. You will never be able to compare the test2 string with the output one, since the output one is filled with underscores, when your test2 is `NULL` terminated after its meaningful content.
8. While variables at the loop scope are valid according to C99 and C11, they are not standard in ANSI C; and it is usually better to not declare any variable in a loop.

Also, "_ spaces" are called "underscores" ;)

---

Here is a code that does what you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 50

int main()
{
    char phrase[LEN];
    char guessed[LEN];
    char guess;
    int i, tries = 0;

    puts("Please enter the secret string:");
    if(fgets(phrase, LEN, stdin) == NULL)
      return 1;
    for(i = 0; i < LEN && phrase[i] != '\n'; i++); // Detect the end of input data.
    for(; i < LEN; i++)                            // For the rest of the input data,
      phrase[i] = '_';                             // fill with underscores (so it can be compared with 'guessed' in the while loop).
    phrase[LEN - 1] = '\0';                        // NULL terminate 'phrase'

    memset(guessed, '_', LEN);                     // Fill 'guessed' with underscores.
    guessed[LEN - 1] = '\0';                       // NULL terminate 'guessed'

    while(strcmp(phrase, guessed) != 0)            // While 'phrase' and 'guessed' differ
    {
      puts("Enter a guess (one character only):");
      if(scanf("%c", &guess) != 1)
      {
        puts("Error while parsing stdin.");
        continue;
      }
      if(guess == '\n')
      {
        puts("Invalid input.");
        continue;
      }
      while(getc(stdin) != '\n');                  // "Eat" the extra remaining characters in the input.
      printf("You entered: %c\n", guess);
      for(i = 0; i < LEN; i++)                     // For the total size,
        if(phrase[i] == guess)                     // if guess is found in 'phrase'
          guessed[i] = guess;                      // set the same letters in 'guessed'
      printf("Guessed so far: %s\n", guessed);
      tries++;
    }
    printf("Well played! (%d tries)\n", tries);
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask questions in the comments, if you are not getting something. :)

Comment: What is inside the while loop you added though? There's a condition but no instructions to be executed

Comment: There is a [`nop` instruction: `;`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP#C). It is used to "discard" the reading until the condition is met. I have edited my answer to explain that. Note that if you want to notice more easily that you are doing nothing in the loop, you can replace the `;` after the `while` with `{}`.

Comment: Doesnt work :(. Simply keeps on asking for guesses without displaying the output and infinitely so.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. It almost works. It prints the ouput string as being one _ space longer than it is and so the strings never match

Comment: Okay I'm going to compile your code and check (I usually use `getc` to read the character, not `scanf`, so maybe there's a glitch I didn't think of, with `scanf`, and I'm going to check it right now).

Comment: As it turns out, there is no glitch in my solution, but there are many errors in your code. Please check the list of the comments I have made on your code (it's not complete at the current time).

Comment: @user3078379 I think you might want to check your code against my solution. Happy coding! :)

Comment: @self. Thanks for your comment, I added a check on the `scanf` return value.

Comment: Disagree about "the best way is to read them and discard what you read (what the code below does, ".  `while(getc(stdin) != '\n');` is an infinite loop when end-of-file is encountered.  Need to break loop on `EOF` also.

Comment: Code should check the return value of `fgets(phrase, LEN, stdin);` to verify it is not `NULL` before using `phrase` as in `... LEN && phrase[i]`

Comment: `while(strcmp(phrase, guessed) != 0)    ... if(scanf("%c", &guess) != 1) ... continue;` is an infinite loop on end-of-file.

Comment: @chux well it was expected to always have an interactive TTY and a human pressing 'return' or 'enter' after the answer, when I wrote that code. So I didn't account for `EOF`s. But you're right.

Comment: Nice promising code like this gets re-purposed to new conditions.  Undocumented limitations obliging  "always have an interactive TTY" can have large consequences.  Consider [Ariane_5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariane_5#Notable_launches) which re-used code beyond its successful prior limits.

Comment: I guess you're right. I'll fix that asap (if I find room on my TODO list ;)

Answer (score 0):

Newline character entered in the previous iteration is being read by scanf. You can take in the '\n' by using the getc() as follows:

```
scanf("%c",&guess);
getc(stdin);
```

..

This changed worked for me. Though the right explanation and c leaner code is the one given by @7heo.tk

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
scanf("%c",&guess);
```

with

```
scanf(" %c",&guess);
```

It should ignore `'\n'`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The strings never match after youve entered all the letters

Comment: While this can work for ignoring the newline, it has the following drawbacks: it also ignores all spaces, tabs or other white-space characters from the input (source: `SCANF(3)`); it will cycle through ALL the input characters (i.e. if you input "abc", it will behave as if you typed 'a' then 'b' then 'c') in the loop before asking the user for another input.